# editing XML files using AWK

Tags: xml, bash, awk

I have a xml file with some empty element fields ie

```
<elementA></elementA>
```

I am writing a bash script that fills up the empty field with a user specified value and saves it as a new xml file.

```
awk "{gsub("<elementA></elementA>", "$XMLVALUE", $0); print $0)" $EMTPYFILE > $NEWFILE
#$EMPTYFILE is a bash variable containing file path of xml file containing emtpy fields
#$NEWFILE is a bash variable file path of new xml file with redirected output from awk
#$XMLVALUE is a bash variable containing the value to be inserted into the field.
```

The output should be the original xml file but with  filled with the value of $XMLVALUE.

However I am getting a variety of different errors, depending on if I am using single or double quotations. I think the problem is that there are multiple levels of parsing by awk and bash and I am mixing up proper handling of bash variables vs awk variables and the use of /.

Comment: As an aside -- all-caps variable names are reserved for system and environment variables. See the relevant section of the POSIX standard at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html -- fourth paragraph -- keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace.

Answer (score 4):

`awk` is the wrong tool for this job.

- It can't escape values to make them valid XML (changing `Yellow & Blue` to `Yellow &Amp; Blue`, or `3<4` to `3&lt;4`) without you doing the work for every single value that needs to be so escaped.
- It can't recognize comments, CDATA sections, or other XML syntax.
- It can't guarantee that the output after performing edits will be valid, conforming XML.

Instead, use [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sf.net/):

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//elementA' -v "$value" <in.xml >out.xml
```

---

That said, to safely pass shell variables' values to awk, use `-v`:

```
# Don't actually use this for XML!
awk -v in_string="$in_string" -v out_string="$out_string" \
  '{gsub(in_string, out_string); print}' \
  "$in_file" > "$out_file"
```

If you want awk to be dealing with literals, however, even this isn't good enough. See the `gsub_literal` function provided in [BashFAQ #21](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021).